# How do you Configure Python Keyring to pull credentials from Windows Credential Manager on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7-x64, python-keyring

I've spent a lot of time researching the keyring package trying to get a simple example to work.  I'm using python 2.7 on a windows 7-x64 machine.  I've installed the package and confirmed that the files are within my Lib/site-packages folder.

In this code snippet from the installation docs what is supposed to go in "system"?

```
import keyring
keyring.get_password("system", "username")
```

When I run the code i get the following error:

> *RuntimeError: No recommended backend was available.  Install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends.*

It seems like it's not recognizing Windows as the backend.  I feel like I'm missing a simple step.  Any help is appreciated including a simple code example of pulling generic credentials from Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Windows 7.  Python 3.6.  Installed from conda, IIRC.  Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally got this working.  The information from Shaun pointed me in the right direction with installing `pywin32`.  From there I did trial and error with creating test credentials in Windows Credential Manager and testing the Python keyring function.

I only got it working with Generic Credentials which is fine for my purposes.  I set Internet or network address to `"test"`.  Username was set to `"test_user"`.  Password was set to `"test123"`.  (Quotes included here for instruction, don't include when entering them.

```
print keyring.get_password("test","test_user")
```

returned the result `"test123"`

Hopefully this information helps somebody else.  Thanks to Shaun for the direction needed to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

You may have to install the `pywin32` package.  Doing so solved the problem for me.

Using `conda`:
`conda install -e environment_name_here pywin32`

Using `pip`:
`pip install pywin32`

On a tangent: For some reason, the code swallows an exception that the windows credential manager class would have otherwise thrown to alert you to this problem.  [Here's the exception](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/3d3066fea9f6b2079916ca515d0d8993c15b5b28/keyring/backends/Windows.py#L61) and [here's where it's caught and thrown away](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/3d3066fea9f6b2079916ca515d0d8993c15b5b28/keyring/backend.py#L189).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  I didn't think I would ever get this answered.  I installed pywin32 and that took care of the exception errors as you described.  

However I think i'm still unclear on the arguments to use in keyring.get_password.  Do you have a quick example you can describe of the credentials you created in Windows Credential Manager and how you extracted the password using keyring?

I've tried the following:
keyring.get_password("Windows, "test_user")
keyring.get_password("Generic", "test_user")

My log output for both results shows "None"

Comment: @BrianJ, you're absolutely welcome.  Mark as answered?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you can do that but instead you can ask the user to give it's credentials using this following commands

```
import admin
if not admin.isUserAdmin():
    admin.runAsAdmin()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually need generic credentials setup in Windows Credential Manager to be passed to the script without any user input to be used in a web scraping application.  

It seems like keyring would provide this functionality but I can't seem to get it to work with a Windows backend.